# How to divide a number in an IFTTT action

Tags: ifttt

I have got Monzo (a bank) and Strava (a fitness tracking app) setup in IFTTT.

There is a pre-existing recipe that saves 1 pence per 10 kilometers when a new activity is created.

I want to create a similar recipe that gives me less money (I basically want to give me the train fare I save when I cycle to work)

I want to get £5 for every 16 miles (or 0.02p / meter)

The distance we get from Strava is in meters so the existing recipe obviously divides the number but I can't figure out how to do this.

How can I perform maths in an action expression?

Comment: I assume you need to create one yourself with this-trigger Strava and that-action Monzo. Does this forum entry help you?
https://community.monzo.com/t/ifttt-monzo-strava-cycling-question/67110/2